# Undefined behavior when trying to call separate functions

Tags: c

This program prints a n x n square, in which the sums of all the rows, columns and diagonals are the same. I managed to write this code successfully without calling separate functions (`create_magic_square` and `print_magic_square` in this case), but with separate functions, the compiler returns a random number (-1073741571).

```
#include <stdio.h>
void create_magic_square(int n, int magic_square[n][n]);
void print_magic_square (int n, int magic_square[n][n]);

int main(void) /*creates magic square, in which the sums of the rows, columns and diagonals are all the same */
{
    int n, magic_square[n][n];
    printf("Enter the number: "); /*n must be odd */
    scanf("%d", &n);
    create_magic_square(n, magic_square);
    print_magic_square(n, magic_square);
    return 0;
}
void create_magic_square(int n, int magic_square[n][n])
{
    int i, j, a, x, y;
    for (i = 0; i <= n-1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= n-1; j++)
            magic_square[i][j] = 0; /*Initializes the n x n matrix */
    }
    i = 0; j = n/2;
    magic_square[i][j] = 1;  /*first put the number 1 in the middle of row 0 */
    for (a = 2; a <= n*n; a++) {
       if (i == 0)
        i = n;
       if (j == (n-1))
        j = -1;

       if (magic_square[i-1][j+1] == 0) { /*If the element up 1 row and over 1 column is not yet occupied */
        i = i - 1;
        j = j + 1;
        magic_square[i][j] = a; /*assigns a to this element */
       }

       else if (magic_square[i-1][j+1] != 0) { /*If the element up 1 row and over 1 column is already occupied*/
        i = x; /*Assigns i to its value in the previous loop */
        j = y; /*Assigns j to its value in the previous loop */
        if (i == (n-1))
            i = -1;
        i = i + 1;
        magic_square[i][j] = a; /*assigns a to the element directly below the previously stored number */
       }
       x = i; /*Stores the current i value */
       y = j; /*Stores the current j value */
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= n-1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= n-1; j++)
            printf(" %3d ", magic_square[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void print_magic_square (int n, int magic_square[n][n]) /*prints the square*/
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i <= n-1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= n-1; j++)
            printf(" %3d ", magic_square[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The compiler doesn't detect any errors or produce any warning, yet it doesn't return anything, even the message in the `printf` (Enter the number)

Comment: The variable `n` is uninitialized when you use it to define the array.  You’ve no idea what size the array is!

Comment: It amazes me that this compiles with an uninitialized warning and not an error. Wild west right here.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler got it. Thank you :D

Comment: Magic squares don't have to have odd row and column counts.  For instance, one of the most famous magic squares of all time is 4x4.

Comment: It's weird that you don't get any warnings, which compiler is this? Also, writing the for loop condition as "`for (i=0; i<n; i++)`" is more idiomatic in C (and shorter compared to `i<=n-1`).

Comment: @Groo I'm using Code::Blocks version 17.12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Jonathan Leffler stated n is uninitialized when you use it to define the array. Define the array after scanf. This way array size will be determined.

```
int main(void)
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the number: "); /*n must be odd */
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n % 2 != 1 || n > 25 || n < 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid size for magic square\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int magic_square[n][n];
    …
```